# Can a procedure with optional parameters be listed in the menu to run macros?

Tags: vba, excel

When you write a procedure in VBA it will appear in the macros list so that users can run it. If you add parameters to said sub, of course it will disappear from the list.

However when I had the parameters as optional and with a default value it stills doesn't show up there. Is it possible to do it, thought?

```
Sub runsomething(Optional ByVal sheetname As String = "setup")
```

Comment: No. You would need an additional calling sub with no parameters that simply calls your main routine. (Note: you can still run the routine from the macros dialog by typing its name, but it will not appear in the list.)

Comment: @Rory: my answer works in my Excel 2013

Comment: Apparently you can! Did not knew that! — Thanks!

Comment: @user3598756 Yes - sorry. As long as you use a Variant and don't supply a default value *in the declaration*, it will work.

Comment: @Rory: yes, that's precisely what I proposed. As a further refinement, should the OP need a variable of string type then he may declare some `dim sheetnameStr as string` and go on with `If IsMissing(sheetname) Then sheetnameStr = "setup" : Else : sheetnameStr =CStr(sheetname)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub runsomething(Optional ByVal sheetname As Variant)

If IsMissing(sheetname) Then sheetname = "setup"
'...
End Sub
```

Comment: In my Excel 2013 it works. I wrote two subs: the first with first line `Sub runsomething(Optional ByVal sheetname As String = "setup")` and the second with first line `Sub runsomething2(Optional ByVal sheetname As Variant)`. after pressing "ALT+F8" the Macro window pops up and there I only see "runsomething2". of course none of them are `Private`...

Comment: It's weird because it doesn't work with a string and you cannot have a default value for it to work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ +1

Comment: see my last comment as to have a string typed variable in your sub in any case. as for the default value you still get it per my posted answer (it defaults to "setup"). If I didn't answer, please clarify your need